# How to hide a label message when a div becomes visible

Tags: javascript, html

I have used a label box to render a "**please wait**" message when the user clicks "**Save**" button. Once the processing gets over, the output gets displayed. My goal is to hide the label once the output is displayed. How do i achieve this.

My code is as follows,

```
 <label id="embedLabel" class="hide" runat="server" visible="false">Please Wait
 </label>  
 <div id="ChannelDIv" class="hide">  
 <textarea id="channellinkCode" runat="server" >  
 </textarea>  
 </div>
```

My goal is to hide the `embedLabel` label once the `embedLabel` is displayed. Am using javascript function on the click event of "**save**" button to show the `embedLabel` div. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: That really depends on what your "save" button does, doesn't it? And you should add the appropriate ASP.NET tags, what you are showing is not pure HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using AJAX then when the output gets displayed **the whole page will refresh** (postback).  So as long as the default state of your `embedLabel` is hidden (`display:none or visibility:hidden`) when this happens it will be hidden.

I can see that you have assigned it the css class `hide`, but you've also set `visible="false"` which means it'll never make it to the client at all.

I think you need to remove `runat="server"` and keep this as a client side label which you only manipulate through JavaScript and CSS (with default hidden) this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that change css class assigned to message label in javascript onLoad() event handler, so after your page is completly rendered it will hide message label.

**edit:**

```
<body onload = "hideMessage()" >

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function hideMessage() {
     document.getElementById('embedLabel').style.display = 'none'
} 

</script>
```

that's what was on my mind when i posted answer, but i agree with Eddy556 that you dont really need it. I missunderstanding yours question initially.

Comment: can u elaborate your suggestion zgorawski?

Comment: Instead of doing that why not just set it as hidden - no need to do anything on page load.